# How to classify ordered labels(ordinal data)?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, predictive-modeling, machine-learning-model, model-selection

I have some data similar to movie ratings and the labels are ordered, like 1 to 10. since the target label is not a nominal but ordinal variable, what types of models should I be using for classifying such data? what kind of losses and metrics to use?

Comment: why do you think the loss functions or the models should be different than other classification tasks?

Comment: because the data is not usual, it is ordinal. and there is relation between each number. i learned that weighted-kappa can be used as metric, but don't know about loss and algos.

Comment: The fact that the target is ordinal does not make the models or the loss functions different in general

Answer (score 0):

In classification problems one usually uses [categorical variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable). An example are [One-hot vector](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f), that have a 1 in the index of the corresponding label and 0 on the rest:

label 3 -> [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

So if you transform your label to a one hot vector, you can now create a mathematical model.

This is accompanied by a [softmax](https://deepai.org/machine-learning-glossary-and-terms/softmax-layer) layer at the end of your model to represent the probability that a given input belongs to each class. You can compare this output vector with the one hot vector from the ground truth using, for example, [cross entropy loss](https://towardsdatascience.com/cross-entropy-loss-function-f38c4ec8643e). This last link shows a nice post that explains the whole procedure.

Comment: one hot encoding is killer regarding dimensionality increase. Instead in many cases other encodings can provide state-of-the-art results. However in this case the target is already encoded